# Applying a function to every element of a vala array

Tags: dictionary, vala

What is the equivalent of the following python code

```
map(func, list)
```

in vala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such shortcut. You have to do a foreach:

```
var res = new YourList ();
foreach (var elem in list) res.add (func (elem));
```